# sqlalchemy: binary column not created?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to use `sqlalchemy` ORM (currently version 1.0.12) to save pictures in a Postgres database. My Python code is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Binary
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://127.0.0.1:54321/warehouse', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

class Picture(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'pictures'

    picture_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    data = Binary()
    filename = Column(String())

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

My problem is that the binary column `data` is not created which one can see with `psql` or in the log of the previous script:

```
2016-05-11 13:07:12,881 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE TABLE pictures (
        picture_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        filename VARCHAR,
        PRIMARY KEY (picture_id) )
```

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you missed something: the `Column(...)` call.

Try

```
class Picture(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'pictures'

    picture_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Binary())    # <---
    filename = Column(String())
```

instead.